# Download .xlsx file in the resourses file with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to download a copy of templete.xlsx that exists in the resources file, but it download a corrupted file.

plugin :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
<configuration>
   <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
   <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
   <nonFilteredFileExtension>xlsx</nonFilteredFileExtension>
   </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

controller :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "download/{fileName}")
    public void downloadTemplateFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        try {
            Path templateFilePath = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI());
            if (Files.exists(templateFilePath)) {
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=".concat(fileName));
                Files.copy(templateFilePath, response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved when i used FileCopyUtils.copy with BufferedInputStream instead of Files.copy as below :

```
 response.reset();
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=".concat(fileName));
                FileCopyUtils.copy(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(templateFilePath.toFile())), response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();
```